# copying values inside a record from one key to other in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongo-shell, mongodb-compass

I am working on MongoDB. I am trying to append some new key-value pairs to my existing collection. I got more than 50 documents in my collection, in all of which I want to update a new key value pair. In the new key value pair I am adding, one of the values of the key should be from one of the existing key value pair of the same collection.
For example:

```js
{ name : "algebra", quantity : 25 }
```

Now I want to update each of the document with

```js
{ category : "maths" , available_quantity : 25 }
```

Without entering distinctly for every document its available quantity. I want it to be picked from it's respective quantity's value, and be inserted in the new key available_quantity.
I am using the code to update the document :

```js
db.books.update( {} , { $set : { category : "maths" , available_quantity : `__ ? __` }, false, true }
```

What best can I put in `__ ? __` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with Aggregation framework:

```js
db.books.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "available_quantity": "$quantity"
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AD6UaRHVGFl)

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked. but I still got a thing to ask. 
Why putting the "$set" key-value inside an array worked whereas removing the array updated the value in the form of string "$quantity" ?

Comment: Because when you use array as second parameter it will apply Aggregation pipeline where you can access the values of the document properties with `$` operator. If you don't pass the array but only update object as a second parameter, then you can not access the value of the property. Consider also upvoting and accepting my answer if it helped you.